# Excel add and copy row values based on the amount of matches

Tags: vba, excel

First of all I'm completely new to VB and have not much experience with Excel.
Second I'm not sure if this is the correct forum to ask this question, but I saw more questions regarding my issue.

I have an Excel sheet with two columns with id's in it. Something like this:
[image]

As you can see in the first picture (in column 1) you have 3 equal id's (in blue). In the second column you have that same id (on second row) just one time. Is there a way to create some sort of function to duplicate the second column as many times as the first column has that id?
So it looks like the second image:
[image]

**EDIT:** The idea of the function/formula is that rows shift down. Not every ID in column 1 has multiple same ID's. For example the black cell is just a single one.Further column A is used as reference and only column b to F should be "changed".

I tried programs like [Kutools](https://www.extendoffice.com/product/kutools-for-excel.html) to accomplish this but without success. Since the sheet has around 15k rows it would take a lot off time to do it by hand.

I'm able to add an empty row with VB when a cell matches a value, but I'm not able to copy.

I tried this which obviously doesn't work:

```
Sub BlankLine()

    Dim Rng As Range
    Dim WorkRng As Range
    On Error Resume Next
    xTitleId                   = "MyTest"
    Set WorkRng                = Application.Selection
    Set WorkRng                = Application.InputBox("Range", xTitleId, WorkRng.Address, Type: = 8)
    Set WorkRng                = WorkRng.Columns(1)
    xLastRow                   = WorkRng.Rows.Count
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    For xRowIndex = xLastRow To 1 Step - 1
        Set Rng                   = WorkRng.Range("A" & xRowIndex)
        If Rng.Value = "0" Then
            Rng.Offset(1, 0).EntireRow.Insert Shift: = xlDown
        End If
    Next
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Is this even possible and is somebody willing to give some directions? Thanks in advance...

Comment: What happened to your rows with 39365627 and 39365640? Are they being shifted down? Are they going to have matching IDs somewhere in this column adjacent to them? Are they always in the correct order? We need to see a bigger set of data, IMO.

Comment: I believe that it may be faster by copying data into a new worksheet rather than inserting so many rows inside your data.

Comment: As a tip, `Application.ScreenUpdating = False` is a good thing to have in your code once it's all working as intended. Until then, it's hiding what's going on and that'll make figuring out issues more difficult. Just comment it out for now (put a single quote `'` at the beginning of the line).

Comment: @dwirony: Yes your absolutely right. I've updated my question.

Comment: @Meules Thanks for the update - in that case my code that I posted below might work for you, however I still can't see what columns you're using/what row you're starting on, etc., so you might have to make some adjustments...

Comment: @dwirony: I'm starting on row 1. Row 1 has headers for the column. Row 2 is the first "data" row.  Columns are A to F. But I'll update the image, one sec.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a small example - without being able to see more of your data, it's impossible to know where to go from here.

```
Sub Test()

Dim i As Long
Dim id As String

For i = 1 To Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    id = Cells(i, 1).Value
    If Cells(i + 1, 1).Value = id And Cells(i + 1, 2).Value <> id Then
        Range(Cells(i + 1, 2), Cells(i + 1, 6)).Insert Shift:=xlDown
        Range(Cells(i + 1, 2), Cells(i + 1, 6)).Value = Range(Cells(i, 2), Cells(i, 6)).Value
    End If
Next i

End Sub
```

[image: img1]

Comment: You were to quick :) I've updated my question as per your request. It's my first time posting such question so I'm not sure which data is needed for an anwer :)

Comment: @Meules just try to include as many 'cases' of data differences as possible in your example

Comment: @dwirony: I've updated the images again. I'm not sure if the amount of rows is important? The problem is in my case that column A has around 13k rows and column B around 8k. Column B is shorter because of the missing id's.

Comment: @Meules Did you try my code? I'm guess it should work now that I can see your layout

Comment: @dwirony: I've tested a small portion of the sheet and it looks like it works! I'm testing a bit more now and let you know immediately.

Comment: @dwirony: I've tested it on the full sheet. Your code works until row 4823. Can that be because of limits or something? While I was typing this it seems that those id's need to be in order. For example I have on row 1 value 1234 and on row 2 1233 then script stops and adds all rows again for all matching values. Any way I think I can find a solution for this. Many thx!!! You saved me :)